# Changes were not applied. Modifications to AndroidManifest.xml require an app restart

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm facing an issue with Android Studio. Whenever I try to 'Restart Activity' or 'apply code changes,' I receive the following error message: **Error running 'app': Modifications to AndroidManifest.xml require an app restart.**

This forces me to restart the app every time, even for minor changes. I have attached a screenshot for reference.

[image]

I have tried invalidating caches, restarting, and rebuilding, but I'm still encountering the same issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you set an automatic versioncode in your build.gradle that changes very frequently?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything version code . I am using Flavour for maintaining debug and production for URL changes